# Asymptote: How to use nested arrays?

Tags: asymptote

How would I create a nested array in Asymptote such as `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and call upon element 1 of array 1 and such?

Comment: Does the discussion in section 2.15 of [this nice tutorial](https://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) help?

Comment: Kind of, but I still don't fully understand the syntax. How would you define such an array such as my example [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] above?

Comment: Generally you are much more likely to get a concrete answer if you post a concrete question. In your case this would be an asymptote code that attempts to use an array. Then the one who is willing to write an answer will know whether you are talking about integers or reals and so on, and in particular does not have to type so much themselves.

Comment: Note to close/reopen-voters: Asymptote (like Metapost) is part of the TeX ecosystem even though its syntax does not resemble standard TeX syntax. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/are-asymptote-questions-on-topic. Also note that the Asymptote tag has 7 questions on Stackoverflow versus 403 on TeX.SX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Illustration in interactive mode:

```
$ asy
Welcome to Asymptote version 2.41 (to view the manual, type help)
> int[][] a = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
> a  // please print a
1   2   3
4   5   6
> a[1][1]  // index-1 entry of index-1 array in a
5
> a[1]  // index-1 array in a
0:  4
1:  5
2:  6
```

Comment: Nice to see you back! And I fully agree with your above comment.